# El instalador de MySQL se ejecuta cada vez que conecto mi cargador

Tags: mysql, hardware

Cada vez que conecto mi cargador al ordenador, me sale esto

```
=================== Start Initialization ===================
MySQL Installer is running in Community mode

Initializing product requirements
Loading product catalog
Checking for product packages in the bundle
Categorizing product catalog
Finding all installed packages.
```

¿Qué es esta frontera? ¿Qué pasa con eso?

Utiliso un Asus Zenbook Flip14

Comment: Ocurre solo cuando conectas el cargador? Has probado si reiniciando sesión te ocurre también? o reiniciando completamente?

Comment: Si, @NicolasOñate en ambos casos

Comment: en ambos casos también te ocurre? o en ambos casos no te ocurre?

Comment: En ambos casos, se produce con regularidad @NicolasOñate . Es realmente extraño. Es como ser espiado

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638238/strange-mysql-popup-mysql-installer-is-running-community-mode

Comment: Que tal esto ???

Comment: Fuck yeah, mate! Me preguntaba si me estaba escuchando el servicio secreto. Acabas de romper mi sueño; @Excorpion ^^
Si traduces la respuesta te daré los puntos

Comment: Tomaré la palabra XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abre el ***Programador de Tareas***

En el *Programador de Tareas* navega a *Biblioteca del Programador de Tareas* > *MySQL* y selecciona ***Installer***.

De la lista en el centro de la ventana haz click derecho en ***ManifestUpdate*** y *desactivalo*.

[image: Disable MySQL ManifestUpdate]

Respuesta desde -> [Strange MySQL Popup “Mysql Installer is running community mode”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638238/strange-mysql-popup-mysql-installer-is-running-community-mode)

Comment: [That's fucking awesome !!!](https://youtu.be/UmZD1_BrQdU?t=28)

Comment: Recuerda marcarla como respuesta, y si es necesario, traduzco la 2da respuesta por que lo explica desde mysql